# Include cordova plugin in ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, import

How can i include this plugin https://programmingcindia.blogspot.com/2016/12/ionic-cordova-plugin-to-read-sms.html?showComment=1501236991517#c4262583798146827634 in my ionic app?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is a combination of Cordova core, Angular 1 and Ionic presentation so basically it's a cordova project. You can install every cordova plugin in to your project by:

Open cmd then open the drive your project is in (C: , E: , etc.):

> E: (for example)

navigate to your cordova project directory

> cd E:/MyCordovaProject/

install the plugin by entering this command

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sms

You will have to read the documents to know how to implement and use the plugin in your js file

Comment: i do it but how i can use variable like angular or SMS? In documentation write how to use this variables? but how iimport them?-No

Comment: Just use it
angular is already in your project when you create an Ionic project.
SMS object will be available to use after you import the plugin successfully.

Comment: Sorry for bad construction of question? but i want to read SMS in my file like 'home.ts'. Is it possible? Iam a newbee in js and ionic